# nginx index page coming instead of actual website in route 53 with ec2 instance

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have hosted my django website in aws ec2 instance
with below ip and pointed to below domain

nginx file

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/myproject
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/myproject/env/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/myproject/myproject.sock myproject.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target



18.221.162.213
http://govtcarrier.in/
```

When i am going 18.221.162.213 in my browser it is coming my website
but when i am going http://govtcarrier.in/ it is showing nginx welcome page.

Please check the screenshots below
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: can you please add your nginx file

Comment: question updated

Comment: add `server_name = govtcarrier.in 18.221.162.213` in your nginx conf file

Comment: Yes.. right. I forgot to add this . thanks .. Hope it will work